# USB stick not in /dev

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning, iso-image

I'm new on this community, newcomer to the Arch distribution, and I hope to post in the good section :)
I think it's a Hardware problem rather than a distribution problem.

I am currently trying several Arch distributions before permanently installing a basic Archlinux. To do this, I create a bootable USB key from downloaded ISOs (after checking the SHA1 and MD5). By reinitializing and formatting the USB key, I think that there was a failure when writing on the key. Now the USB is not available in `/dev/sdb`

**Story**

First, I created a bootable key and installed Arcolinux on my machine. Then I decided to do the same for Antergos from current Arcolinux.

When reinstalling the USB key: the writing of the ISO worked, then I rebooted the machine to boot on the key, but the machine did not succeed.

Indeed, looking at the contents of the key, from gparted, the space was UNALLOCATED.  I tried to create a new partition on the device, then to format everything in FAT32, but nothing seems to work: gparted announces that everything worked, but by disconnecting and reconnecting the key, I see that the space is still UNALLOCATED from gparted.

As I can not partition the key, I still tried to install the ISO directly on /dev /sdb by running this command again :
`#  dd bs=4M if=/Downloads/antergos.iso of=/dev/sdb status=progress oflag=sync`

Maybe it was my mistake...

Now, the machine can not boot on the key, and since Arcolinux, the USB key is not detected at all. That is, the key is no longer available in `/dev`. So, I looked for several solutions on different sites, including the forum Archlinux. But nothing seems to solve the unavailability of the key in `/dev`.

Could you help me ?

**Informations**

```
[pev@zorin ~]$ uname -a
Linux zorin 4.19.12-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Dec 21 13:56:54 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux


[pev@zorin ~]$ pacman -Qi linux
Name            : linux
Version         : 4.19.12.arch1-1
Description     : The Linux kernel and modules
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://git.archlinux.org/linux.git/log/?h=v4.19.12-arch1
Licenses        : GPL2
Groups          : base
Provides        : None
Depends On      : coreutils  linux-firmware  kmod  mkinitcpio
Optional Deps   : crda: to set the correct wireless channels of your country [installed]
Required By     : b43-firmware  broadcom-wl
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 76,82 MiB
Packager        : Jan Alexander Steffens (heftig) <jan.steffens@gmail.com>
Build Date      : ven. 21 déc. 2018 14:55:51 CET
Install Date    : dim. 23 déc. 2018 20:21:01 CET
Install Reason  : Explicitly installed
Install Script  : Yes
Validated By    : Signature
```

With the connected USB key:

```
[pev@zorin ~]$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 467,9G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0   8,8G  0 part [SWAP]
```

With the connected USB key:

```
[pev@zorin ~]$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 840 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FDDDDDF9-DFB8-467E-BEA6-FC5583C92D02

Device         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       4097     618497    614401   300M EFI System
/dev/sda2     618498  981751960 981133463 467,9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  981751961 1000206899  18454939   8,8G Linux swap
```

With the connected USB key:

```
[pev@zorin ~]$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3d (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-LM (rev 21)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

With the connected USB key:

```
[pev@zorin ~]$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b52c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub



[pev@zorin ~]$ dmesg
[...]

[  480.627769] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
[  485.630997] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR mismatched command completion event
[  485.631023] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  487.764483] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  487.970867] usb 1-2: device not accepting address 28, error -62
[  487.971004] usb usb1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
[  493.097799] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Command completion event does not match command
[  493.097806] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR mismatched command completion event
[  493.097811] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR mismatched command completion event
[  614.483738] INFO: task kworker/1:2:176 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  614.483748]       Tainted: P           OE     4.19.12-arch1-1-ARCH #1
[  614.483750] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  614.483755] kworker/1:2     D    0   176      2 0x80000000
[  614.483778] Workqueue: usb_hub_wq hub_event
[  614.483784] Call Trace:
[  614.483807]  ? __schedule+0x29b/0x8b0
[  614.483821]  schedule+0x32/0x90
[  614.483830]  schedule_timeout+0x311/0x4a0
[  614.483843]  ? usb_start_wait_urb+0xa2/0x160
[  614.483852]  wait_for_common+0x15f/0x190
[  614.483862]  ? wake_up_q+0x70/0x70
[  614.483890]  xhci_alloc_dev+0x96/0x2e0 [xhci_hcd]
[  614.483905]  usb_alloc_dev+0x6f/0x310
[  614.483915]  hub_event+0x4fa/0x15b0
[  614.483932]  process_one_work+0x1eb/0x410
[  614.483943]  worker_thread+0x2d/0x3d0
[  614.483953]  ? process_one_work+0x410/0x410
[  614.483960]  kthread+0x112/0x130
[  614.483969]  ? kthread_park+0x80/0x80
[  614.483979]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
```

Comment: Sounds like your USB key is stuffed.